# Geonode Restrict Upload

Tags: geonode, administration

An institution wants to have layer/document uploads done only by specific users. 
The "normal" user shall be restricted from uploading a layer/document.

Can this be achieved in the recent version of geoNode?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, by default only registered users can upload files. Geonode administrator can give privilages to only "staff users" to upload files. You can also hide the "upload button" from the web-page for non-staff or non authenticated users, by editing the html files (layer_detail.html and document_detail.html), using

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
. (whatever you want to be seen only by authenticated users)
{% endif %}
```

(same with user.is_staff)